# Finite difference methods with discontinuity in the payoff function

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, differential-equations, finite-difference-method, finite-difference

I have implemented a finite difference scheme for pricing options using a Black-Scholes-like model. I tested my implementation on a call option, and found that it gave extremely inaccurate results. I investigated intermediate values in my computations, and I suspect that my inaccurate results are caused by the discontinuity in the payoff function.

The payoff function:

$$\text{Payoff}(S) = \max(S-K, 0) \hspace{.4em} \text{for some strike price } K \text{.} $$

My scheme requires that I calculate $\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{S}}$ and $\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{S}^2}$ at two points near $K$. At these points, $rs\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{S}}$ causes a minor issue, but $\frac{1}{2}s^2v\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{S}^2}$ explodes when I use a first order central approximation.

What kinds of solutions exist for this problem? I'm trying to keep my derivative matrix $A$ (meaning $U' = A U+x$) "oblivious" to the type of derivative (or, in the case of a call option, the strike price) for simplicity of implementation. "Hack"-ish solutions are very welcome.

An example:
I set the strike to K=110. Three nearby asset prices are 107.336, 109.983, and 112.732. If you compute first order central approximations at the point 109.983, you get

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}s^2v\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{S}^2} &= \frac{1}{2}(109.983^2)*v*\Big( 0.140*0 +   (-0.274) * 0 +  0.134858*(112.732-110)    \Big) \\
&=2,228.32*v
\end{align}

At all other points, for the first time step, $\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{S}^2}=0$.

Comment: Part of the issue I'm having is that it seems to me that all discretizations should suffer from a discontinuity of the payoff function. I can't see why, then, this particular discontinuity should feel insurmountable without resorting to complex solutions like the projection method.

Comment: It's probably not related to this - but you should apply the log-transform to your PDE to move out of the S domain into the LogS domain. It simplifies your PDE by removing explicit dependence on S in the coefficients.  That said, you can still price in the S space in PDE without it blowing up, so I suspect something else has gone awry! Can you post relevant segments of your code in the question?

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan My code is a several-thousand-line implementation of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4087.pdf. I have thoroughly, thoroughly tested to confirm that it conforms to the paper. I have added an example to the OP that can demonstrate what I am seeing.

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan does translating the problem to the "LogS" domain improve accuracy of computations, or does it just simplify things? I'm seen the transformation in Shreve's _Stochastic Calculus for Finance_, but I'm having trouble finding it discussed in the context of finite difference methods.

Comment: Ok don't post thousands of lines of code. And yes LogS both simplifies the calculations and improves their accuracy, so it's worth looking at. You might have large 2nd derivatives at strike, at expiry, but you also discretise in time - so I'd expect taking a small dt will reduce the magnitude of this first step's contribution. Actually good point, if you are performing explicit Euler discretisation in spatial dimension, you need to be careful over the length of dt step. What is your dS and dt step sizes?

Comment: Actually I think I know at least one place you seem to be going wrong - in your definition of d2U/dS2, nowhere do I see you dividing by dS^2. I ignore the fact your spatial steps are unequal in size, which would mean the calculation of the second derivative needs to weight the partitions accordingly. I'd suggest your read John Hull's book before you delve further into Shreve!

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan sorry, yesterday I decreased the time step size from t = .01 to t =.0005 and got significantly better results. Before, many of the "option prices" I was getting from the model were negative. Now they appear like normal option values, although the values are wrong. Instead of off by $-300$ near $K$, they are off by $-6$. That was with no other changes to the program. I spent a while testing before I responded, and have decided that this is just due to the stability of the scheme. I still need to address the discontinuity in the payoff.

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan I use the nonuniform $dS$ suggested by the paper (page 5). The coefficients used in the central scheme calculation of $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S^2}$ are cached in my program, and that is what $0.140$, $−0.274$, and $0.134858$ are in the OP. They are correct (although truncated to keep the question neat); I have checked them by hand. I am quite sure based on my tests that the problems are caused by the discontinuity in the payoff.